# header redirect not working on server but working on localhost

Tags: php

I'm using bluehost as my webhost, I'm having a few problems. The code below is my point of confusion.

```
<?php
include '../init.php';
error_reporting(0);
?>
<div class='container'>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/responsive.css">    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/bootstrap/css/responsive.min.css">
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="SignIn.css">
<title>SoundBooth - Sign in</title>
<link rel="icon" href="../Images/Logo.png" type="image/x-icon"/>
</head>
<body  background="../Images/BGMain.png">
<div class='signinLabel'>Sign in</div>
<div class='bg'></div>
<div class='user'>Username</div>
<div class='pass'>Password</div>
<form action="index.php" method='POST'>
  <input name='Username' autocomplete="off"class='usr' type="text" style='height:34px;'/>
  <input name='Password' autocomplete="off"class='pas'type="password" style='height:34px;'/>

  <input type='submit' class='submit' value='Log in' ></input>
</form>
<a class='forgotPass' href="#">(Forgot password)</a>
<div class='no-account-label'>Don't have an account? |</div>
<a class='no-account-button' href="/signup">Sign up</a>
<?php
 if (empty($_POST) === false){
    $username = $_POST['Username'];
    $password = $_POST['Password'];

    if (empty($username) || empty($password)){ ?>
            <div style="float:left;margin:-415px 200px;width:500px;text-indent:100px;"class="alert alert-error">You need to enter a username and password!</div>
            <?php
        }elseif (user_exists($username) === false){?>
            <div style="float:left;margin:-415px 170px;width:500px;text-indent:100px;"class="alert alert-error">We can't find that username! Have you <a style='color: rgb(185, 74, 72);' href='../HTML/signup.html'>registered?</a></div>
            <?php
        }elseif (user_active($username) === false){ ?>
            <div style="float:left;margin:-415px 200px;width:500px;text-indent:100px;"class="alert alert-error">You haven't activated your account!</div> <!--Remove this-->
            <?php
        }else{

            $login = login($username, $password);
            if ($login === false){ ?>
            <div style="float:left;margin:-415px 200px;width:500px;text-indent:100px;"class="alert alert-error">The username or password you have entered is incorrect!</div>
            <?php
            }else{
                $errors[] = 'Logging In...';
                $_SESSION['user_id'] = $login;
                if (isset($_SESSION['user_id'])){
                mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET `online_offline`='1' WHERE `user_id`='$_SESSION[user_id]'");
                }
                header("Location: http://sound-booth.com/");
                exit();
            } 
        }
    }
    echo output_errors($errors)
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

is the link to the script. It works in localhost, but not in my actual server. Not even the header() redirect works.

Could somebody please explain this?

**Solution:**

```
ob_start();
```

Comment: The first step when / before asking help would be NUKING statements like `error_reporting(0);`....

Answer (score 8):

best option is to use like this.

```php
// Use this line instead of header
echo "<script>location='your_url.com'</script>";
```

Comment: In case of using url, this code is working. But if I using php method instead of url, it gives **Internal Server Error**. I want to redirect to another page using php method like this, `echo "<script>location='$initResponse->getPaymentPageUrl()'</script>";` Please give idea..

Answer (score 7):

Headers must be set before any output is sent. You are sending a lot of HTML to the user before doing that `header()` call. Perhaps its working in one environment but not in another because `output_buffering` is set on your localhost php.ini but not on the server.

You should rework your code to make sure `header()` is sent before any stuff, but if you want to just get it working append `ob_start()` to the beginning of your code, it will enforce the buffering.

Answer (score 3):

use
`ob_start();` just after `<?php` and use `ob_end_flush();` at the end of your document.

Comment: I have got multiple header redirects within `if`s. But this does not work here. What could I do to make it work?

Answer (score 2):

HTTP headers must be sent before the HTTP response. I.e., you must call [`header`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) *before* echoing anything else or sending any HTML.

Chances are, the reason it works on your local server is because you have configured [output buffering](http://php.net/manual/en/book.outcontrol.php) there. You can insert a call to [`ob_start();`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php) at the top of the page to enable output buffering within the script. Then, since the HTML will be buffered until the script is done, the redirect header can get to the browser first, as it must. Or, you can rework the script to put the `header` call at the top.

Comment: For some odd reason nothing was effected, and gave the same results.

Comment: @SammyLopez I'm sure there must be an error message. Turn `error_reporting` from `0` to `-1` (all) to see what PHP says is going wrong.

Comment: Error: PHP Warning:  Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home1/soundbo3/public_html/header.php:1) in /home1/soundbo3/public_html/login/index.php on line 58

Comment: @SammyLopez Well there's your answer. You cannot output *anything* before a `header` call. But line 1 of header.php is doing so. You'll need to stop it from doing that, perhaps by not including that file when you want to redirect, or else move the call to start output buffering to the *very* beginning.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Location: http://sound-booth.com/");
```

it goes after text output.

Use OB_start() or change your code.

Comment: How would I integrate ob_start()?

Comment: Check my answer, it explains the use of ob_start()

Comment: @Sammy Lopez: place `ob_start()` in the beginning of the php code and `ob_end_clean();` at the end. That should be enough. And remove `<div>` that is before `<html>`

Answer (score 0):

You probably have your error reporting turned off which is why you won't get an error message.

header() does not work if you have even a white space before it. You would need to put it above all your string outputs in order for it to work.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "A white space"?

Comment: White space could be anything that you can't see with the naked eye. e.g. a new line, or a space between two words. So in essence, you can't output anything before a header()

Answer (score 0):

OP,

You have `<div class='container'>` **before** your opening `<html>` tag (which is then closed before `</body>`.

Try moving `<div class='container'>` after you opening `<body>` tag.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

one the very first line of your page use

```
<php ob_start();?>
```

then below header file use

```
ob_end_flush();
```

for example like this.

```
   <?php
ob_start();
?>
<?php
//Get values from the post Operation
require_once 'db/conn.php';

    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

        //extract values from the $_POST array
        $id = $_POST['id'];
        $fname = $_POST['firstName'];
        $lname = $_POST['lastName'];
        $dob = $_POST['dob'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $contact = $_POST['phone'];
        $specialty = $_POST['specialty'];

        //call crud Funtion
        $result = $crud->editAttendees($id, $fname, $lname, $dob, $email, $contact, $specialty);
        //redirect  to index.php
        if ($result) {
        header("Location: viewrecords.php");
        ob_end_flush();
        
        } else {
            echo "error";
        }
    }
```

Comment: use ob_end_flush(); at the end of the php is not working, as @Vibhu suggested use at after the header('location index.php'); ob_end_flush(); it worked like a charm. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

In your php configuration turn on the object buffering. This setting can be found in your hosting dashboard.

Answer (score -2):

I think `ob_start()` function calling is the best idea for this problem. The header function can be call his attribute just after a logical statement. This is passing the value just taking it's previous value.

Refer: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php