# php login file is redirecting me to the users folder in xampp but not in the cpanel

Tags: php, html, xampp, cpanel

My login script when am using xampp as server is redirecting me to the users folder after successful login , but when i upload to the cpanel it just reloads and not redirect. But when i type the folder of the users after the domain name it shows the users is already logged in. Like www.goo.com/users it will take to the users index file as successful login. What can i do for proper redirecting.

```
<?php
    require_once('../includes/config.php');
    $_SESSION['timestamp']=time();
?>
<div class="row"><br><br><br>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <p style="color: green">Login Procedures</p>
      <i class="fa fa-cc-paypal fa-2x" aria-hidden="true">
      <div style="font-size: 15px;">- Login Details will be sent to your email aproximately 20 minutes after payment. </div>
            </i>
            <img src="images/mpesa.png" alt="mpesa" id="mpesa" class="img-responsive" width="50" height="10">
            <div style="font-size: 15px;">
            - Login using the payment confirmation code and mobile phone number without the country code after payment.
            </div>
            <?php
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];

        $result = $dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username= :username AND password= :password");
        $result->bindParam(':username', $username);
        $result->bindParam(':password', $password);
        $result->execute();
        $rows = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);
        if($rows > 0) {

            $result=$dbh->prepare("SELECT * FROM tb_users WHERE username=:username");
            $result->bindParam(':username', $username);
            $result->execute();
            while($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $res_id = $row['username'];
                $curr_status = $row['user_status'];
            }

                if($curr_status=='deactive') {
                    $message = "Sorry <b>$username</b>, You've Exhausted Your Subscription. <p>Make a new Subscription to login or write to admin for Bonus Days.</p>";
                }else{
                    $_SESSION['username'] = $res_id;
                    header("location:users/index.php");
                }

        }
        else{
            $message = 'Wrong Credentials!';
        }
    }
?>
                <div id="signin" class="tab-pane fade in active"><br>
                    <form class="form-signin" id="login-form" method="post">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-7">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-envelope-o fa-fw"></i></span>
                                <input type="text" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email / Phone" required>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class="input-group col-md-7">
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-key fa-fw"></i></span>
                                <input class="form-control" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Password" id="myInput">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div>
                <?php
                    if(!empty($message)) {
                        echo "<p style='color: red; padding: 2px;'>".$message."</p>";
                    }
                ?>
            </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Access" class="btn btn-success"/>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [header redirect not working on server but working on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398808/header-redirect-not-working-on-server-but-working-on-localhost)

Comment: Thanks i found the answer. I used echo "<script>location='your_url.com'</script>";

Comment: Alright, beware though, PHP redirects are better if you can as with the JavaScript one you're causing the client to load the page before the redirect, whereas with the PHP one it sends the proper header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers must be set before any output is sent. You are sending a lot of HTML to the user before doing that `header()` call. Perhaps its working in one environment but not in another because output_buffering is set on your localhost `php.ini` but not on the server.

You should rework your code to make sure `header()` is sent before any stuff, but if you want to just get it working append `ob_start()` to the beginning of your code, it will enforce the buffering.

See [also](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15398808/header-redirect-not-working-on-server-but-working-on-localhost)